# Spellcheck Data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

We have a large database with hundreds of tables that have lookup text stored in them with spelling errors from when the application was originally written offshore.  Is there a way to run a spellcheck on the data in sql server so we can find all of these errors quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Export your data to Excel.
2. Distribute the sheets to multiple people to break up the work load
3. Have them run spell check to identify the misspelled words.
4. Gather up the bad records and create update statements from the db.
5. Don't offshore applications where English spelling is important.

EDIT: I should have pointed out, you might use the spell check to identify the issues but you want human eyes on the actual data as well as suggested fixes. Thus, being able to spread the work around to run the spell check is important. There won't be any fully automated solution that will catch everything, or worse it will catch too much and muck the data up worse.

Comment: number 4 is number 5 now, I thought I should clarify a bit. I had a similar situation once with test items in a db (think questions and answers for an assessment test). The only way we could do it was pull the text from the db, distribute the files to as many people we had who could spell, have them make the edits and send them back.

Comment: I would +2 for the edit if I could. I imagine there will be a lot of incorrect word use that would pass a spell check, like `you're` for `your`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

One thought - You could write a CLR function to access the spell checker included with Microsoft Word. See: [Walkthrough: Accessing the Spelling Checker in Word](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa168503%28v=office.11%29.aspx) for a starting point.

Comment: That requires MS Office to be installed on the server though and some production environments won't allow it. Of course, exporting to Excel (say via SSIS) might have the same gotcha - except in that case the data can be exported to .CSV and then opened in Excel. It's far more common for workstation machines to have Office installed though, so they might be able to get away with it if the CLR is run against a local database on a workstation.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled across this one.

Another way to do this is using Microsoft Access, using ODBC, link to the tables on SQL side, then open the table in access and run the spellcheck in Access, you can update the corrections on the fly.