# Coding replace misspelled with correct from another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Using SQL Server 2014, how can I correct spelling the values in a column (need code please)?

The following is a sample of my data :

```
 fID    Country 
 -------------------------------
 1      pakistan 
 2      bangladish (mar, 2016)
 3      vitnam (jul, 2015)
 4      hondoras (2000) 
 5      japan (apr, 2015) 
 6      marocco (2001)
```

As you see there are spelling errors in the `country` column. What I need is to fix these spelling mistakes without changing anything else - just country names.

Like this :

```
CorrectCountry
---------------
Morocco 
Bangladesh 
Vietnam 
Honduras
```

I already created a table with the correctly spelled country names. But I'm not sure how to use it or is there any specific way to correct that.

**NOTE**: I have more than 2000 records - I can't fix it by hand, also the countries is 57 names

The desired table:

```
fID     Country 
--------------------
 1      Pakistan 
 2      Bangladesh (mar, 2016)
 3      Vietnam (jul, 2015)
 4      Honduras (2000) 
 5      Japan (apr, 2015) 
 6      Morocco (2001)
```

Comment: Although it's not the best solution, it may be sufficient to use Sql Server's built in  SOUNDEX support. Have you ruled that out for your purpose?

Comment: Also, this may help [Spellcheck data in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505970/spellcheck-data-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to go with fully automated solution for this request. 
You can correct the data in multiple iterations

Step 1: Flag exactly matched records. This will help to reduce the number of records that you need manual interactions.

```
UPDATE t1 
SET t1.IsValidated = 1
FROM country t1
INNER JOIN CorrectCountry t2 ON T2.Country = T1.Country
WHERE ISNULL(t1.IsValidated,0) = 0
GO
```

Step 2: Flag matched records using SOUNDEX. Always manual validation is needed.  go through the data in select list before proceed the update

```
SELECT * FROM country t1
INNER JOIN CorrectCountry t2 ON SOUNDEX(T2.Country) = SOUNDEX(T1.Country)

UPDATE t1 
SET t1.Country = t2.Country
    , t1.IsValidated = 1
FROM country t1
INNER JOIN CorrectCountry t2 ON SOUNDEX(T2.Country) = SOUNDEX(T1.Country)
WHERE ISNULL(t1.IsValidated,0) = 0

GO
```

Step 3: What is still pending?  I would suggest to compare manually

```
SELECT * FROM country t1
WHERE ISNULL(t1.IsValidated,0) = 0
```